# I am new in Flutter, how can I add Drawer and Tab bar both aligned same line/one next to another?

Tags: flutter, drawer, tabbarcontroller, flutter-appbar

[In the snap there are drawer and tab options. Both are shown side by side, all in same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIQpR.png) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: SegmentedControl());
  }
}

class SegmentedControl extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SegmentedControlState createState() => _SegmentedControlState();
}

class _SegmentedControlState extends State<SegmentedControl> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false, // This way it will not open
      drawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:     CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(children: {
      0: Text('Segment 0'),
      1: Text('Segment 1'),
      2: Text('Segment 2'),
    }, groupValue: 0, onValueChanged: (newValue) {}),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => // Ensure Scaffold is in context
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't knew about CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl class. This going to be helpful.

Comment: if it's helpful, please mark as answer~ thanks!